# how can I pass $@ arguments to a script in an alias

Tags: bash

I have created a small alias that will list files and display the number of files at the end. However I fail in passing additional input to the alias.

```
alias ll='ls -lFh --group-directories-first $@; numFiles=`ls -l $@ | wc -l`; echo $numFiles" files"'
```

while `ll` works as expected `ll /home` does not list the content of the home directory

Comment: There is no simple way for aliases. Use a function. `ll() { yourCodeHere; }`. You *could* use `alias="bash -c ..."`but that's longer and less efficient than a function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Socowi with a function it works

```
ll() {
  ls -lFh --group-directories-first $@;
  numFiles=`ls -l "$@" | wc -l`;
  echo $numFiles" files"
}
```

Comment: The usage of `$@` makes only sense in double quotes: `"$@"`. Otherwise it is the same as `$*`and word split happens. Same for `${NAME[@]}`

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post.

Comment: And I edited the first occurrence of $@. Because of 6 chars rules, I added trash and can't remove this trash.